# OpenCV: Accessing values of a matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am using the OpenCV function decomposeHomographyMat(). Because I want to decompose my H1 and H2 matrices I have got from the OpenCV function stereoRectifyUncalibrated().

Just for testing I wanted to multiply the rotation and translation back together to see if the result are the same and everything works correct.

```
decomposeHomographyMat(H1, Mat(Identity), result_rot, result_trans, result_normals);

Matx44f rotM(result_rot[id].at<float>(0,0), result_rot[id].at<float>(0,0), result_rot[id].at<float>(0,0), 0,
               result_rot[id].at<float>(0,0), result_rot[id].at<float>(0,0), result_rot[id].at<float>(0,0), 0,
               result_rot[id].at<float>(0,0), result_rot[id].at<float>(0,0), result_rot[id].at<float>(0,0), 0,
               0, 0, 0, 1);
    Matx44f transM(1, 0, 0, result_trans[id].at<float>(0,0),
                   0, 1, 0, result_trans[id].at<float>(0,1),
                   0, 0, 1, result_trans[id].at<float>(0,2),
                   0, 0, 0, 1);

H1 = Mat(transM) * Mat(rotM);
```

I know that for the rotM matrix I am referencing the same value all the time, this is jut temporary.

My problem is, that if I print out result_rot[id] and rotM I get weir result:

```
result_rot[id]: [0.9920521909211247, -0.1258265282306712, 0.0003678069998755973;
 0.1258266147675855, 0.9920522232074044, -0.0002223635722913286;
 -0.0003369043855492455, 0.0002668761040765017, 0.9999999076363849]

rotM: [-0.015474273, -0.015474273, -0.015474273, 0;
 -0.015474273, -0.015474273, -0.015474273, 0;
 -0.015474273, -0.015474273, -0.015474273, 0;
 0, 0, 0, -0.99892187]
```

The value -0.015474273 is not even in the original rotationmatrix and the value 1 seems to be stored as -0.99892187.
I also tried to replace float with double, then the result changes again but still not correct.

How can I properly get the correct value that was stored in that matrix? and what is going wrong here?

Comment: Can you print `result_rot.type()`?

Comment: all indices of your `rotM ` are filled with  `result_rot[id].at<float(0, 0)>` , is it a typo?